# 2nd monitor not working properly

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, vga, dvi

Im using 2 monitors, the first one im using dvi, the second one, hdmi to vga adapter (vga TV/Monitor, plugging in the hdmi port on my graphics card (gtx 1070 g1 gaming));

If i turn on my pc with both monitors connected, it reboots by itself (only the first time), if i let it reboot, it doesn't recognize any of the monitors.

if i turn on the computer with the second monitor (hdmi to vga adapter) unplugged, after i logon to windows, i first connect the hdmi to vga adapter, then i connect the vga cable to the adapter, i can use both monitors normally, if i turn off or reboot the computer, i have to do this all over again.

so, can anyone help me with this one ? thanks!

Comment: HAve you tried different cables? Update the drivers?

Comment: Nvidia drivers are up to date, im trying to get a displayport to vga adapter to see if it works.

Comment: What are models of your monitors? What are the CPU, GPU and motherboard of your PC?

Comment: How old is that second monitor that you'd try to go for VGA?

Comment: Just an old TV/Monitor i have, i use it because why not, its 22", my main monitor is 23", so they work well together